# How many entities does Stack Overflow have?

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

I'm studying Computer Engineering and this year my second-rate and I decided to make Stack Overflow's ER diagrams. How many entities does Stack Overflow have?

Comment: This question belongs on [meta] of [meta.se], not here. This site is for programming related questions, not questions about SO itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a diagram I found on SlideShare:

[image]

Source: https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/full-text-search-in-postgresql